# Cómo ordenar las columnas de fecha y hora - Datatables

Tags: javascript, datatables, jquery-ui

Estoy haciendo una tabla en al cual me trae fecha y hora, ahora quiero ordenarla de menor a mayor la fecha.

He intentado con este ejemplo

> [Ejemplo que me guio](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18)

Ahora si bien es cierto de acuerdo a mi tabla viene hacer el formato de fecha:
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm - 28/12/201 08:00

[Formato de Fecha](https://ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSHEB3_3.3.2/com.ibm.tap.doc_3.3.2/loc_topics/c_custom_date_formats.html)

Les dejo la foto para que puedan ver el formato y la tabla en general.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí les dejo mi código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
        $.fn.dataTable.moment('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm');
        let TableList = $('#example')
        table = TableList.DataTable({
            autoWidth: true,
            dom: "Bfrtip",
            lengthChange: true,
            ordering: true,
            pageLength: 12,
            responsive: true,
            sAjaxDataProp: "",
            select: true,
            ajax: {
                url: '{% url 'api_mostrar_programacion_nave' %}',
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    targets: 0,
                    data: "foto",
                    render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                        return '<img class="imagenpuerto" src="'+data+'" width="200" height: "200">';
                    }
                },
                {data: "manifestado"},
                {data: "nave"},
                {data: "tipo_nave"},
                {data: "nombre_linea"},
                {data: "nro_viaje"},
                {data: "agente_maritimo"},
                {data: "eslora"},
                {data: "eta"},
                {data: "etb"},
                {data: "etc"},
                {data: "etd"},
                {data: "carga"},
                {data: "proyecto_articulo"},
                {
                    targets: -1,
                    data: "reporte_servicio_url",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        if (data)
                            return `<a href="${data}" target='_blank'>
                                    <button class="btn btn-tipoA btn-xs" >Ver+</button>
                                </a>`;
                    }
                },

                {
                    targets: -1,
                    data: "acta_maniobra_urls",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        var _html = "";
                        if (data.atraque_url)
                            _html += `<a href="${data.atraque_url}" target='_blank'>
                                    <button class="btn btn-tipoA btn-xs" >Ver+</button>
                                </a>`;
                        return _html;
                    }
                },

                {
                    "targets": -1,
                    "data": "acta_maniobra_urls",
                    render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        var _html = "";
                        if (data.desatraque_url)
                            _html += `<a href="${data.desatraque_url}" target='_blank'>
                                    <button class="btn btn-tipoA btn-xs" >Ver+</button>
                                </a>`;
                        return _html;
                    },
                }
            ],


        });
    });
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas compañeros !

La respuesta es según el formato de fecha en esta instancia es Dia / Mes / Año y Hora y minutos -> el formato es el sgte:

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD/MM/YYYY H:mm');
```

también tenemos que agregar estas librerias:

[moment.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js)

[datetime-moment](https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/sorting/datetime-moment.js)

Nada más eso es todo.